# Parse local file in gwt

Tags: json, gwt, smartgwt, gwt-rpc, jsni

I'm developing my first application in GWT.I have a case, when the user uploads a file, the app needs to parse the file and show its content in the UI.User can then confirm that the data is correct, and then click "save" to uplaod the contents to server.How can i achieve this is GWT?. I came across some of the post,
[How to read local (Client) file with GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905919/how-to-read-local-client-file-with-gwt)
[Read text file in google GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708306/read-text-file-in-google-gwt)
[Reading a very large local XML file using GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078759/reading-a-very-large-local-xml-file-using-gwt)

But in all the above post, they suggest to upload the file to server and then get the response to do any necessary actions.But in my case, i don't want to upload the file until the user sees the file content in my app and he clicks on "save".

P.S : There is a cancel option in my app.So user can click on cancel , even after he selects a file.So i don't want to make a server call, until he clicks on "save".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do needs modern browsers supporting the html5 [file-api](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) (almost browsers nowadays even IE10+), otherwise you always need to upload files to server side before visualising or processing it.

To process directly files in client side you can use [lib-gwt-file](http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-file), there is no so much documentation about how to use the library but the javadocs. There is a [sample](https://github.com/laaglu/lib-gwt-file-test) project which you  can use as reference as well, take a look to the live [demo](http://www.vectomatic.org/gwt/lib-gwt-file-test-latest/lib-gwt-file-test.html).

If you need to support IE9, you have to use server side approach, gwtupload facilitates the work, since it allows out-of-the-box adding and removing temporary files for the server session before you actually send your ajax request to save data.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve in GWT without using any external libs?

Comment: Of course, lib-gwt-file is written in GWT so you could do, but following the DRY principle I would not repeat the work done by others :-) . You need a lot of [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) code to wrap the file-api if you are confident writing jsni that is your option. You can use [Elemental](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/elemental.html) though which is part of gwt, but it is experimental and only works for chrome browsers.

Comment: I'm new to GWT and am not much comfortable with JSNI.lib-gwt-file is a licensed product? or it comes along with the gwt plugin?.Can you give me more details on this lib-gwt-file??

Comment: Yes that is normal, we, people using gwt don't want to deal with jsni nor js which causes unexpected errors, we are confortable with java and we trust in 3party java libraries for gwt.  lib-gwt-file is licensed under GNU Lesser. I don't understand your second question, gwt is not a plugin but a sdk for producing javascript which run in any browser from java. lib-gwt-file is not a plugin but a java library thought for gwt. I have not contributed with lib-gwt-file but I know it is well maintained and works well. There is no so much documentation except from diving in code and examples.